# acl permission in nodejs with express framework

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I am working on a nodejs with express framework.

I want to create acl permission in a nodejs with express freamwork.
I am try with [acl package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl#backend)

server.js file:-

> Require acl package and database connect with that syntax.

```
const node_acl = require('acl');
var database = mongodb://localhost:27017/society_managment
let acl = null;

mongodb.connect(database, (error, db) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
   acl = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db, '_acl');
});
```

route.js file:-

```
 var acl = require('acl');
 acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());
 acl.allow([
{
    roles:['Admin'],
    allows:[
    {resources:'/admin/chairman', permissions:'*'},
    ]
}
]);
 module.exports=function(app,req){

 app.route('/admin/chairman')
.get(acl.middleware() , chairman.ChairmanList);

 }
```

> Insufficient permissions to access resource show this error

how can i use acl.middleware() anything wrong in my code

please help me
thank you,

Comment: You can always write your own middleware to handle this

Comment: please give me  example if possible

Comment: Ok wait ,let me write an answer

Comment: ok i am waiting

Comment: did you solved this or still waiting for the solution ?

Comment: waiting for solution

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue.I tried this way to resolve that issue .

```
      var acl = require('acl');
      acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());
      acl.allow([
        {
           roles:['Admin'],
           allows:[
             {resources:'/admin/chairman', permissions:'*'},
           ]
         }
       ]);
        acl.addUserRoles('joe', 'Admin') //joe username who loggedIn           
        const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
          if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
              next()
          }
          res.redirect('login')
        }
        app.get('/api/users', [isAuthenticated, acl.middleware()], (req, res) => {
            res.render(__dirname + '/views/user.ejs');
        });
```